# replace pattern in LINUX

Tags: linux, bash, shell

2.txt

> "platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price":
>   "32.25","Qty": "3"}
>
> "platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price":
>   "32.25","Qty": "3"}

I want to replace `,*:*{` with `,`

o/p:

> "platform": "iPhone","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
>
> "platform": "android","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty":
>   "3"}

This is what i tried:

```
sed s/,*:*{/,/g 2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,*` in your sed regex means match zero or more occurrences of `,` and `:*` means match zero or more occurrences of `:` symbol.

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/,[^:]*:[^{]*{/,/' file

"platform": "iPhone","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}

"platform": "android","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

OR

```
$ sed 's/,[^{]*{/,/' file

"platform": "iPhone","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}

"platform": "android","SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```